# Replace Text with Javascript or jQuery by query selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Good afternoon guys.
I would like to replace two texts on my Wordpress website with javascript or jQuery.
This is the page: https://www.schoolandvacation.cloud/anno-scolastico-estero/classic-student-exchange-program/

I need to change:

1) the text "All Tours Attributes" that is on a label with dynamic for (the for change every time that page is loaded)

2) the text "All Tours Categories" that is the first option select on Dropdown menu.

The HTML is generated by Wordpress.

Someone can you help me please?

I try to use this method by query selector but it doesn't work:

```
var selector = "document.querySelector("#search-filter-form-7170 > ul > li.sf-field-taxonomy-tour-attribute > ul > li.sf-level-0.sf-item-0.sf-option-active > label");
var el = document.querySelector(selector);
el.innerHTML; = "New Text";
```

Answer (score 0):

the selector variable should only contain the selector and not the document it self.
it should be

```js
var selector = "#search-filter-form-7170 > ul > li.sf-field-taxonomy-tour-attribute > ul > li.sf-level-0.sf-item-0.sf-option-active > label"
var el = document.querySelector(selector);
el.innerHTML = "New Text";
```

Comment: maybe your selector is not valid try the closest selector possible.